# When should I use .net Framework data types versus language datatypes?

Tags: c#, .net, types

When should I use:

```
Int32 myint = 0;//Framework data type
```

vs

```
int myint = 0;//C# language data type
```

What are the similarities/differences? I seem to recall being told that there are performance differences? Is this true?

Comment: Do you mean Int32 instead of Int?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C# the language-defined keywords for data types are just aliases for their respective BCL types. So `int` is exactly the same as `Int32`, `long` is the same as `Int64`, etc.

In general I'd think it's best to stick with the language-defined type names, though. There are definitely no performance differences as those aliases are resolved by the compiler.

Comment: My C# compiler happily recognized `Main` with `System.String[]`. Where did you get this bit from?

Comment: Remember someone having this problem here on SO. Might have been wrong, didn't try. I removed that bit.

Comment: Visual studio has a problem recognizing Main(String[]) as a valid Main.

Comment: Note, this is not true in some other languages (like Java) where using Integer generates a Boxed reference type.

Comment: nader: The question was about .NET. And the dichotomy of primitives and wrapper classes is usually clear to most people writing Java :)

Answer (score 5):

`int` is an alias for `System.Int32`, `string` is an alias for `System.String`. There are no differences.

That said, it's better practice to use `int` and `string`, not their System equivalent, mostly for readability. If you use a source style checker such as [StyleCop](https://web.archive.org/web/20101226140646/http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis), it will enforce replacing all `System.String` and `System.Int32` declarations with their shorter equivalent.

Comment: Since usually all source files have a `using System;` at the top you wouldn't have to qualify the type name with its namespace on each use :)

Comment: You wouldn't have to due to the using statement, but in the case of int and string, you would never have to.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting: [The compiler doesn’t allow you to type enum using the “Int32” but it does when you use “int”](https://web.archive.org/web/20200119050036/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/caustin/archive/2005/08/05/49267.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I used to advocate using C# language aliases over CLR types, but I changed my preference to using CLR types after I heard that Jeffery Richter advocates the CLR type in his book CLR via C#, my first hand dealing with other devs new to the CLR, the ability to see that the CLR, instead of C#, is the center of attention, as well as color clues between reference and value types helps in visually parsing code quickly.